# I need to give a Jenkins parameter in groovy script and mark it as madatory if the env selected is prod

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-groovy

[image]
I need to make the CR number mandatory if prod is selected here

I searched how to make the parameter mandatory, but I couldn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [Validating String Parameter](https://github.com/jenkinsci/validating-string-parameter-plugin).

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        validatingString(
            name: 'param1', 
            defaultValue: '', 
            regex: /^[0-9]+$/, 
            failedValidationMessage: '', 
            description: 'Numbers only parameter example'
        )
    }

    stages {
        stage("Check") {
            steps {
                echo "${params.param1}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another option is to check the value when starting the run and fail it.

```
if (params.crNumber == null) {
    error("CR Number is mandatory")
}
```